# How to convert a part of a Html Page build using asp.net to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to covert this RED BOX area in to a pdf document so i can use it as report in my system. How can i do this, What kind of a pdf converter i should use and how? (im using bootstap

[image]

Comment: Voted to close your question since it's asking for us to recommend a library, which isn't allowed. Instead, you should do your own research. Googling "c# create PDF" got me plenty of handy results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this tool it is great for HTML to pdf Converstion
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

here is the code which converts HTML String into PDF bytes.

```
public byte[] Convert(string source, string commandLocation)
        {
            Process p;
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = commandLocation;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\" ;// Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);

            // run the conversion utility
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

            // note: that we tell wkhtmltopdf to be quiet and not run scripts
            string args = "-q -n ";
            args += "--disable-smart-shrinking ";
            args += "";
            args += "--outline-depth 0 ";
            args += "--page-size A4 ";
            args += " - -";

            psi.Arguments = args;

            p = Process.Start(psi);

            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter stdin = p.StandardInput)
                {
                    stdin.AutoFlush = true;
                    stdin.Write(source);
                }

                //read output
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                byte[] file;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (read <= 0)
                            break;
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    file = ms.ToArray();
                }

                p.StandardOutput.Close();
                // wait or exit
                p.WaitForExit(60000);

                // read the exit code, close process
                int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
                p.Close();

                if (returnCode == 0)
                    return file;
                else
                    LogManager.Log("Could not create PDF, returnCode:" + returnCode);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.Log("Could not create PDF", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                p.Close();
                p.Dispose();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

here "source" is the HTML Code, while commandLocation is the full File Path of wkhtmltopdf.exe which you can downlaod from above link.
this function returns byte[] which is the pdf file you can save it on the disk or return to the browser by writing **Response.Write(byte);**
and change the MIMIE Type.

Comment: Thax, I'll try to do it.

Comment: When i debug the code, when it comes to ' p = Process.Start(psi); ' code line it sends and error "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: basically you need to download the wkhtmltopdf.exe and set the of this exe here.it seems it does not find the wkhtmltopdf.exe file

Comment: i just found a great article you can see here.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884204/HTML-to-PDF-in-ASP-Net

Comment: How should i save returns byte[] as a pdf file on the disk?

Comment: you can do this , File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.pdf", arryBytes);

Answer (score 1):

If paying for a solution is not a dealbreaker, then I would suggest using [ABCPdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm), you can use the API or even send the HTML from a view, like this:

```
public static byte[] PdfForHtml(string html)
{
    // Create ABCpdf Doc object
    var doc = new Doc();

    // Add passed in HTML to ABCpdf Doc object
    int theID = doc.AddImageHtml(html);

    // Loop through document to create, potentially, multi-page PDF
    while (true)
    {
        if (!doc.Chainable(theID))
        {
            break;
        }

        doc.Page = doc.AddPage();
        theID = doc.AddImageToChain(theID);
    }

    // Flatten the PDF
    for (int i = 1; i <= doc.PageCount; i++)
    {
        doc.PageNumber = i;
        doc.Flatten();
    }

    // Get PDF as byte array to eventually pass back 
    // in controller action method
    var pdfbytes = doc.GetData();

    doc.Clear();

    return pdfbytes;
}
```

Now you need a way to generate the HTML that would have been sent back as the original view, like this:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(Controller controller, 
                                        string viewName, 
                                        object model, 
                                        string masterName)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, 
                         viewName, 
                         masterName);

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, 
                                          viewResult.View, 
                                          controller.ViewData, 
                                          controller.TempData, 
                                          sw);

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need to create a controller action method to use the above two methods, something like this:

```
public ActionResult BuildPdf(YourModel model)
{
    // Return view if there is an error
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }


    // Render view output to string
    var report = RenderViewToString(this, "BuildPdf", model, "BuildPdf");

    // Convert string to PDF using ABCpdf
    var pdfBytes = PdfForHtml(report);

    // Return file result
    return File(pdfBytes, 
                System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf,     
                "Your_PDF_File_Name_Here.pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thax a lot mate, I'll try this

Answer (score -2):

Send it to a virtual printer or use a converter library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).